# reload the same div from the same url

Tags: jquery

I have contentEditable divs, (that can be changed by the client,) how can I add a button to refresh the content of the div, It should remove all the children of this $(this) div and reload them from the server, to refresh the content & revert the changes made by the user.

Problem is, that there are many of these editable divs and all share the same classes, so I can't just specify an id or class to .load() - What seems to be the problem is that I can't use jquery selectors as a fragment to fetch, so I would need an id for each one of the editable divs.

I Have tried the following

.load() the url (which is "window.location") using $(this) as the id

with no luck

```
  There are many of these divs! I appended a button to each editable div,
  <div contentEditable class="editable">`<p>abc...</p>`<button>refresh</button></div>  


 $('.editable button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.editable').children('*').remove();
    $(this).parent('.editable')
    .load(window.location + " " + $(this).parent('.editable').children('*') );
    return false;
    })
```

What is wrong? & What is the best approach?

Comment: @bazmegakapa have tried to clear it up a little

Answer (score 1):

What you want with this code: `window.location + " " + $(this).parent('.editable').children('*')` ?

If you have an especific URL to load each editable content you can set this URL as an attribute of the editable element, but if you have only one editable area and is the all page content, you only need to get the page again (like a reload)

So, solving case 1:

```
$('.editable button').click(function(){
  var $editable = $(this).closest('.editable');
  var reloadURL = $editable.attr('reload-url');
  $editable.load(reloadURL);
})
```

For the case 2, you just have to:

```
$('.editable button').click(function(){
  var $editable = $(this).closest('.editable');
  $editable.load(window.location.href + " #" + $editable.attr('id'));
})
```

The `.load()` method replace the content of an element by the content from the response of an ajax request

Comment: case 2 is what's needed, to refresh this div's content. & your solution isn't working

Comment: you have just one editable area per page? if yes, you just need to reload the page, use `localStorage.clear()` and then `window.location = window.location`

Comment: No. I have over 20! & I don't want to refresh the whole page only the content of this 1 div that is one of the many editables so that is why I used $(this)

Comment: How do you want to reload just one div loading the whole page?

Comment: it's in the documentation [http://api.jquery.com/load/] $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container'); loads the fragment of the page into the current page & disgards the rest

Comment: ok, srry about it. Check the answer now and comment the results :]

Comment: yes it would work if it had an id, but I'm asking to do so without adding a separate id to each editable! seems like its not possible ! but I appreciate your help so far.